# What does StandardFilter exactly do in Lucene5.3.1?

Tags: java, lucene, information-retrieval

I didn't find any example in the documentation. It just says: "Normalizes tokens extracted with StandardTokenizer.".

What does documentation mean with: "Normalizes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API documentation:

> Normalizes tokens extracted with StandardTokenizer.

In reality, though, the answer is:  *Absolutely nothing.*

```
public class StandardFilter extends TokenFilter {
  public StandardFilter(TokenStream in) {
    super(in);
  }

  @Override
  public final boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
    return input.incrementToken(); // TODO: add some niceties for the new grammar
  }
}
```

That's about as simple as a `TokenFilter` gets.  It takes in tokens, and spits them right back out again, unchanged.

In Lucene 2.X it did some work on apostrophes, removing dots from acronyms, etc, and in 3.X and 4.X, it kept that code around for backward compatibility.  As of 5.0 that backwards-comptability support has been removed, and the filter no longer does anything at all (though it certainly may in the future).

Comment: "In Lucene 2.X" [...] "removing dots from acronyms". What does this task now?

Comment: The tokenizer itself does.  In 2.X, StandardTokenizer used a much different algorithm (see [ClassicTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/ClassicTokenizer.html)).  Now it implements the much more robust [UAX #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/), which specifies how to handle those cases (See rules [WB6 and WB7](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#WB6), particularly).

Comment: I have a last question: is there a site where I can find a simple explanation of what StandardTokenizer does without reading all that complicated and frightening grammar? Maybe a schematic explanation...

Comment: The simple explanation is it's a language-agnostic attempt to split full text into words.  If you want details about what it considers word boundaries to be, the UAX document there would be the right place to look.  Section 4 (Word Boundaries) is really all you need to worry about.